# How to compile a preprocessed file into object file using VS compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, cl

cl.exe (Visual Studio C/C++ language compiler) compiles source file to preprocessed file with the /P flag e.g. `cl /P Source.c` creates Source.i

I want to compile this Source.i (not the Source.c) into Source.obj. How should I do it? Can't find a flag that takes preprocessed file as an input.

Comment: Preprocessor output should not contain anything preprocessable. What fails if you try compiling it normally? Can you show the command line you're using?

Comment: A preprocessed file is simply an ordinary C++ file. It can be compiled without any flags.

Comment: Just rename it to something with a `.c` extension and compile that without the `/P` flag.    The preprocessor will still be executed (it is a phase of compilation) but, since the file is already preprocessed, should have no observable effect on the object file.    Bear in mind that a preprocessed file may make use of compiler-specific extensions, so you won't (typically) be able to compile the preprocessed code using another toolchain.

Comment: since output file has "i" extension compiler is unable to detect langue. So probably you have to use some flag to force language or add receptive extension to filename

Comment: I already have the `.c` file, so I can directly compile it to `.obj` and `.lib` directly for that matter. What I am looking for is to move the compilation from preprocessing to compiling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. It's a valid C++ source file that just goes to your compiler. (Though it won't be a portable source file, since all the toolchain's own standard library gubbins, and whatever else, have been expanded.)

The only trick here is that usually the "intermediate" step is done for you by the front-end, taking the preprocessed source and passing it to the "real" compiler. But you can still just do that yourself.

However, you may want to rename it so it has a nice C++-like extension. Otherwise, you can pass [`/Tp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/tc-tp-tc-tp-specify-source-file-type?view=vs-2019) to force your file to be treated as C++, regardless of extension. (For GCC this would be `-x c++`.)

The other thing to note is that it's then still going to run a preprocessing step on your file, not knowing that it's no longer needed (all the preproc directives have already been expanded by your first step), so that's a little wasted additional time. But then this is not (or should not be) a typical workflow.

```
cl /P Source.c
cl /Tp Source.i
```

Comment: The `cl` flag for compiling C++ code is `/TP` (and for C code, `/TC`).

Comment: As per [MSDN documentation] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/tc-tp-tc-tp-specify-source-file-type?view=vs-2019) /Tp flag is to specify a source file which contains C++ code in it irrespective of the file extension

Comment: Isn't there any option which can take the compilation from preprocessing to compiling without starting it from scratch?

Comment: @Sisir Yes that's what I said!

Comment: @Sisir No there isn't